# Cómo llamar a múltiples url mediante AJAX con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Se puede llamar a múltiples url mediante AJAX?
Estoy utilizando una API de cotizaciones de criptomonedas y quiero pintar en pantalla diferentes precios.
Pero tengo que utilizar diferentes URL.
Cómo podría hacer?

Les dejo el código que tengo:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{

    const url = "https://criptoya.com/api/bitstamp/btc";
    $.get(url,function(respuesta,estado){

        console.log(respuesta);
        console.log(estado);
        if (estado === "success"){
            let misDatos = respuesta;
                $("body").prepend(`
                  <div>
                    <h3>${new Intl.NumberFormat().format(parseInt(misDatos.last))}</h3>    
                  </div>`);
        }   
    });
})
```

Comment: Con un bucle, recorriendo un array de urls?

Comment: Hola pablo! Lo recorrería con un for, pero como haría? Perdón si es media tonta la pregunta, pero estoy aprendiendo jaja. Cuando encapsulo las url como array en una variable me tira error

Comment: Crea una función que reciba la URL como parámetro para ejecutar la petición AJAX y la mandas llamar cuantas veces sea necesario. Si es con arreglo, entonces dentro de un ciclo.